# Why is my code returning a non response error? I am new to symfony2 and trying to implement the blog example explained in the symfony book

Tags: php, symfony

This is the code in my controller. Now according to the symfony book, this should allow the URL /blog/my-blog-post to be loaded with  the slug variable acquiring a value of my-blog-post. However on execution, my controller returns an error "The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?" Any idea on how to resolve this?

Controller code

```
<?php
    namespace Acme\BlogBundle\Controller;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

    class BlogController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/blog/{slug}", name="blog_show")
     */
    public function showAction($slug)
{
//...
}
}
```

Comment: Search 'Symfony2 Controller' on google and you'll see that [your function should return something](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html). You may read the basics on Symfony2 before trying to implement specific things that rely on these basic concepts...

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell since you removed the most important part ... the body of your showAction($slug) function... This function should create a "response". If request-response does not make sense to you you should turn to a basic tutorial.

Comment: I repeat myself Jadek : Please master the basics before trying to go on an upper layer. You can't run if you don't know how to walk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you do not have the @Template annotation, you should render a template in your action return:

```
// renders app/Resources/views/hello/greetings/index.html.twig
return $this->render('hello/greetings/index.html.twig', array(
    'name' => $name
));
```

More here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#rendering-templates

Comment: I have actually read the basics on Symfony2. I am going page by page of the Symfony book. And yes, i figured that my function had to return something.

Comment: OK, have fun with symfony2. If this answer is ok for you, you can mark it as OK by checking it.